# Wrap span tags with f.submit

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I was trying to style my Submit button on a Form.. The normal submit code:

```
<%= f.submit "Text here" %>
```

My style:

```
    <div class="ui-button button1">
      <span class="button-left">
        <span class="button-right"> Post your Answer </span>
      </span>
    </div>
```

Basically i need the submit button to wrap the span tags so it becomes a functional button...
But somehow i can't figure out how.

What am i missing ?

**EDIT** The Css for the Button

```
.button1 { height: 38px; }
.button1 .button-left,
.button1 .button-right { height:38px;backgroundimage:url("http://i.imgur.com/7ZIueSj.png")}
.button1 .button-left { padding-left: 35px; background-position: 0 0; }
.button1 .button-right { padding-right: 35px; background-position: 100% -114px; height: 38px; line-height: 35px; font-size: 13px; color: #fefefe; text-shadow: 0 0 5px #dd3400; overflow:hidden }
.ko-kr .button1 .button-right { font-family: Dotum; }
.button1:hover .button-left { background-position: 0 -38px }
.button1:hover .button-right { color: #fff; background-position: 100% -152px; }

.button1.disabled .button-left,
.button1.processing .button-left { background-position: 0 -76px; cursor:default }
.button1.disabled .button-right,
.button1.processing .button-right { color: #a79fa0; text-shadow: 0 0 5px #000; background-position:100% -190px; cursor:default }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `f.submit` is just an helper, based on [`submit_tag`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.0.0/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb#L426) helper, that writes an HTML input tag. There is nothing special in there.

Likewise, the helper [`button_tag`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.0.0/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb#L486) is designed to render a button, a submit button by default. You can use it or, even simpler, you can simply replace it with pure HTML.

```
<button type="submit">
<div class="ui-button button1">
  <span class="button-left">
    <span class="button-right"> Post your Answer </span>
  </span>
</div>
</button>
```

Whether it's a good idea to include all this markup inside a button... well, this is another story.

You cannot replace the `button` with a link `a` because there is no submit type for a link. You can simulate it via javascript, but it discourage you to follow this way.

Comment: Hey Simon, Thanks for answering. How would you suggest fitting the Button style code in a "button" the right way ? (I included my Css Code)

Comment: The code itself is too complex. Have a look at Bootstrap for example. They have a very simple class for buttons you can attach to any input, link or button element.

Answer (score 0):

"submit" is a form element, while "a" is HTML link.

Of course you are free to add any style or inside tags there, but you should not change a submit tag to a link.

Comment: I know that :) the a class is just the style of the button (showing that it is a button). My problem is wrapping the submit around the span tags.. Any solution to that ?

Comment: I don't know your exact style but this should not be a tough task. You can play with it until finding the style you want. Bootstrap has already wrap form elements with control divs.

Comment: The exact style are the spans Billy... I think you don't understand my problem (maybe i described it poorly).. I have already the style i want (The span tags) The problem i face is wraping it with the f.submit so it becomes functional..